# Finding mean of three columns at a time in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  a dataframe of 10000 rows and 200 columns; 'df'. All the columns are numeric. I need to find the mean of three columns at a time, for example; mean of first three columns(0:3), then mean of next three columns (3:6) and so on. In the end I will end up with 67 columns. But I need to have the index same as the original index. 
Here is my approach:

```
l1=list(np.arange(0,200,3))

def func4(row):
    data=row[0:200]

  for i in l1:
     if i!=198:
        dat1=data[i:i+3]
        np.mean(dat1)

    else:
        i=i-1
        dat1=data[i:i+3]
        np.mean(dat1)
return row
```

df.apply(func4,axis=1)

But here is the error I am getting, which I understand, but I am not being able to rectify it:

*ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 67), indices imply (1, 200)*
Help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: This question and answer here is similar and better : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963347/find-average-of-every-three-columns-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
# I am creating a random dataframe to test
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(1000,200)))

# Use list comprehension to create list of 3 column means then concatenate all
# I am using `df.ix` to take 3-column slices
pd.concat([df.ix[:,i:i+3].mean(axis=1) for i in range(0,len(df.columns),3)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Highly appreciate your help. Can you advise me one more issue of vectorization? Suppose new dta frame df_new has 67 columns now, since we took mean of three columns at a time. And I want to give new labels to columns of df_new. Here is my approach.Your feedback fro improvement is appreciated.

Comment: `l3=np.arange(2000,2017)
    l3=list(l3)
    l4=['q1','q2','q3','q4']
    l5new=[]
    for i in l3:
        for j in l4:
            k=str(i)+j
            l5new.append(k)
    
   
    
    idx=df_new.columns.tolist()
    for i in idx:
        df_new = df_new.rename(columns={i:l5new[i]})`
     as you can see I am using **for** loop here, which is tedious.

Comment: If you want to change column names you can simply do this: `df_new.columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3' .....]`. If you want to change the name of only a few columns using `df.rename`  would be a better solution. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)