# Renaming columns when using resample

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert years into 4 quarters as example- `2000q1, 2000q2, 2000q3, 2000q4`.

I am using the below code

```
mdf = mdf.resample('Q',axis=1).mean().rename(
    columns=lambda x: '{:}q{:}'.format(x.year, [1,2,3,4][x.quarter >1]))
```

But the output I am getting is 
`2000q1, 2000q2, 2000q2, 2000q2`.

Please suggest where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[1,2,3,4][x.quarter > 1]` translates to `[1, 2, 3, 4][True]` (i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 4][1]`) if `x.quarter` is larger than 1, or `[1, 2, 3, 4][False]` (i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 4][0]`) if `x.quarter` is 1 or less. As a result this would return 2 for quarters larger than 1, and 1 for quarter 1.

```
'{}q{}'.format(x.year, x.quarter)
```

should work fine without any indexing. See the renaming part in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40963455/2285236).

Comment: Its Working. Thanks